# Is there an analogous to tryFind for the new Result type in F# 4.1?

Tags: f#, option-type, f#-4.1

The F# language contains the Discriminated Union type `option<'T>`. Several modules contain useful functions `XYZ.tryFind` whose return value is an object of type `option<'T>`. (Examples: `List.tryFind`, `Map.tryFind`, `Array.tryFind`). `F# 4.1` added the type `Result<'S,'T>` which is analogous to `option<'T>` but provides more information. Are there functions analogous to `tryFind` for the `Result<'S,'T>` type?

The code below is an attempt at creating such a function.

```
let resultFind (ef: 'K -> 'T) (tryfind: 'K -> 'M -> 'T option) (m: 'M) (k: 'K) =
    let y = tryfind k m
    match y with
    | Some i -> Result.Ok i
    | None -> Result.Error (ef k)

let fields = [("Email", "jdoe@xyz.com"); ("Name", "John Doe")]
let myMap = fields |> Map.ofList
let ef k = sprintf "%s %A" "Map.tryFind called on myMap with bad argument " k
let rF = resultFind ef Map.tryFind myMap // analogous to tryFind
rF "Name"
rF "Whatever"


val resultFind :
  ef:('K -> 'T) ->
    tryfind:('K -> 'M -> 'T option) -> m:'M -> k:'K -> Result<'T,'T>
val fields : (string * string) list =
  [("Email", "jdoe@xyz.com"); ("Name", "John Doe")]
val myMap : Map<string,string> =
  map [("Email", "jdoe@xyz.com"); ("Name", "John Doe")]
val ef : k:'a -> string
val rF : (string -> Result<string,string>)

[<Struct>]
val it : Result<string,string> = Ok "John Doe"

[<Struct>]
val it : Result<string,string> =
  Error "Map.tryFind called on myMap with bad argument  "Whatever""
```

Also, why does the `[<Struct>]` declaration appear above the `Result` objects?

Comment: The F# `Result` DU itself has the `[<Struct>]` attribute so that it compiles to a .NET struct instead of a class. Structs are value types, so they avoid GC and are faster in many cases. More info: https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-design/blob/master/FSharp-4.1/FS-1014-struct-discriminated-unions.md

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The standard library doesn't have these functions, and it shouldn't. With a function like `tryFind`, there is really only one thing that could go wrong: the value can't be found. Therefore, there is really no need for comprehensive representation of the error case. Just a simple "yes/no" signal is enough.

But it is a legitimate use case when, in a known context, you need to "tag" the failure with specific error information, so that you can pass it out to your higher-level consumer.

However, for this use case, it would be wasteful and repetitive to invent a wrapper for every function: these wrappers would be completely identical except the function that they're calling. Your attempt goes in the right direction by making your function a higher-order one, but it does not go far enough: even though you're accepting the function as parameter, you've "baked in" the *shape* of that function. When you find yourself in a need to work with a function of, say, two arguments, you'll have to copy&paste the wrapper. This ultimately comes from the fact that your function takes care of two aspects - calling the function and converting the result. You can't reuse one without the other.

Let's try to stretch the approach further: break up the problem into smaller pieces, then combine them together to get the complete solution.

First, let's just invent ourselves a way to "convert" an `Option` value into a `Result` one. Obviously, we'd need to provide the value of the error:

```
module Result =
    let ofOption (err: 'E) (v: 'T option) =
        match v with
        | Some x -> Ok x
        | None -> Error err
```

Now we can use this to convert any `Option` into `Result`:

```
let r = someMap |> Map.tryFind k |> 
        Result.ofOption (sprintf "Key %A couldn't be found" k)
```

So far so good. But the next thing to notice is that the error value is not always needed, so it would be wasteful to compute it every time. Let's make this computation deferred:

```
module Result =
    let ofOptionWith (err: unit -> 'E) (v: 'T option) =
        match v with
        | Some x -> Ok x
        | None -> Error (err())

    let ofOption (err: 'E) = ofOptionWith (fun() -> err)
```

Now we can still use `ofOption` when the error value is cheap to compute, but we can also defer the computation by using `ofOptionWith`:

```
let r = someMap |> Map.tryFind k 
        |> Result.ofOptionWith (fun() -> sprintf "Key %A couldn't be found" k)
```

Next up, we can use this conversion function to create wrappers around functions that return `Option` to make them return `Result`:

```
module Result =
    ...
    let mapOptionWith (err: 'a -> 'E) (f: 'a -> 'T option) a =
       f a |> ofOptionWith (fun() -> err a)
```

Now we can define your `rF` function in terms of `Result.mapOptionWith`:

```
let rF = Result.mapOptionWith
           (sprintf "Map.tryFind called on myMap with bad argument %s")
           (fun k -> Map.tryFind k myMap)
```

Comment: Thanks. I learned a lot. I just replaced `(fun k -> Map.tryFind k myMap)` with `Map.tryFind >< myMap` where `><` is a flip operator, hope that is Ok.

Comment: Yes, flipping the function would be in the same direction. I did not want to mention this possibility, because I didn't know whether you were familiar with the concept, and did not want to needlessly overload the explanation. That said, I must also mention that I would not recommend implementing flip as an operator: this will make your code that much more confusing for new people, and even for yourself in a year.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin I'd even go further and say "flip" is a terrible function; it doesn't factor out any significant logic, and any logic involving it would be easier to understand if written inline as a single function. I've been doing F# for years and still have a lot of trouble reading tricky code like that.

Comment: @Asik - I respectfully beg to differ. For f x y, one is certainly used to currying the first argument and using f x instead of (fun y -> f x y). One can as easily do "flipped currying" using f >< y for (fun x -> f x y). The >< operator just means you are "currying" the second argument instead of currying the first argument.